# How can I install OpenBoard?

Tags: software-installation, dpkg

Here is the output of my installation attempt:

```
calvin@Calvins-PC:~/Downloads$ sudo dpkg -i 
openboard_ubuntu_16.04_1.4.1_amd64.deb 
Selecting previously unselected package openboard.
(Reading database ... 425932 files and directories currently 
installed.)
Preparing to unpack openboard_ubuntu_16.04_1.4.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking openboard (1.4.1) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of openboard:
openboard depends on libavformat-ffmpeg56 (>= 7:2.8.14); 
however:
Package libavformat-ffmpeg56 is not installed.
openboard depends on libavcodec-ffmpeg56 (>= 7:2.8.14) | 
libavcodec-ffmpeg-extra56 (>= 7:2.8.14); however:
Package libavcodec-ffmpeg56 is not installed.
Package libavcodec-ffmpeg-extra56 is not installed.
openboard depends on libswresample-ffmpeg1 (>= 7:2.8.14); 
however:
Package libswresample-ffmpeg1 is not installed.
openboard depends on libswscale-ffmpeg3 (>= 7:2.8.14); however:
Package libswscale-ffmpeg3 is not installed.
openboard depends on libavutil-ffmpeg54 (>= 7:2.8.14); however:
Package libavutil-ffmpeg54 is not installed.
openboard depends on onboard; however:
Package onboard is not installed.
openboard depends on libqt5multimedia5-plugins; however:
Package libqt5multimedia5-plugins is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package openboard (--install):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.13.3-11ubuntu1.1) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.23- 
1ubuntu3.18.04.1) ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon (0.5.3+18.04.20180207.2- 
0ubuntu1) ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.60ubuntu1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
openboard
```

Could someone help me figure out why this won't install please? And also tell me what to do to get it working.

Comment: Did you tried `sudo apt install ./openboard_ubuntu_16.04_1.4.1_amd64.deb`? From where you have downloaded OpenBoard? What is your Ubuntu version?

Comment: The right install command for also installing the dependencies is : `$ sudo gdebi
openboard_ubuntu_16.04_1.4.1_amd64.deb`

Comment: Related question: https://askubuntu.com/q/1093952/53743.

Answer (score 2):

I got here because the OpenBoard website proposes that I download the Ubuntu 16 version, but I'm on Ubuntu 18, so when running

```bsh
sudo gdebi openboard_ubuntu_16.04_1.5.4_amd64.deb
```

I was getting the message:

```
Dependency is not satisfiable: libavformat-ffmpeg56
```

You can see if that's your case with:

```bsh
cat /etc/os-release
```

In my case, I'm on Ubuntu 18.

You can then check the appropriate version on the [OpenBoard releases page](https://github.com/OpenBoard-org/OpenBoard/releases/).

I downloaded the `.deb` of [Version 1.5.3 for Ubuntu 18](https://github.com/OpenBoard-org/OpenBoard/releases/tag/v1.5.3-ubuntu18) and successfully installed it with:

```bsh
sudo gdebi openboard_ubuntu_18.04_1.5.3_amd64.deb
```

Oddly, when I open the application it tells me that there is a new version available and it sends me to the official download page where it re-proposes me to download the Ubuntu 16 version. Just ignore it.