# Where can I get "libavformat-ffmpeg56" from?

Tags: software-installation, dependencies

It is a dependency for OpenBoard, could someone tell me where to get it please since it is not something that Ubuntu can obtain by itself (I think it's an old version).

Comment: Related (for some background): https://askubuntu.com/q/1093940/504066

Comment: @PerlDuck indeed. I was unsure where to reply, in the end I posted my answer on the other one: https://askubuntu.com/a/1258427/53743.

Answer (score 6):

When the OS is later than Ubuntu 16.04, please add (temporarily) some "xenial" lines to `/etc/apt/sources.list` :

`sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list`

Lines added, my example :

```
deb http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main
deb http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial universe
deb http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates universe
```

Next : `sudo apt update`

... And you can then install the package: `sudo apt install libavformat-ffmpeg56`

- The install test was done OK with Ubuntu 18.04 - amd64.

Answer (score 0):

Install libavformat-ffmpeg56

```
sudo apt-get install libavformat-ffmpeg56
```

have been upgraded in Ubuntu 16.10, 17.04, 17.10, 18.04 and 18.10 to libavformat57.

```
sudo apt-get install libavformat57
```